# Can I replace Initialize() and Close() method calls with a using block somehow in this snippet?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, streamwriter, using-statement

Is there way you  can suggest to help to get rid of calling the Initialize() and Close() methods and replace it a using block?

Or this approach is totally OK?

(Idea is to ensure the Writer will be disposed when a consumer of FooWriter writes some strings and finishes with this.)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var writer  = new FooWriter();

            writer.Initialize();

            foreach (var s in args)
                writer.Write(s);

            writer.Cose();
    }


public class FooWriter
{

    public StreamWriter Writer;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Writer = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt", false);
    }

    public void Write(string line)
    {
        if(Writer==null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(Writer, "Writer"); // Guard Writer

        Writer.WriteLine(line);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        Writer.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by making your `FooWriter` an `IDisposable`. and moving the initialization into its constructor:

```
public class FooWriter : IDisposable {

    public StreamWriter Writer;

    public FooWriter()
    {
        Writer = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt", false);
    }

    public void Write(string line)
    {
        // You do not need to guard the writer, because constructor sets it
        if(Writer==null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(Writer, "Writer"); // Guard Writer

        Writer.WriteLine(line);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Writer.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make FooWriter implement IDisposable and call Initialize() in the constructor, you can then use at as follows:

```
class FooWriter : IDisposable
{
   private StreamWriter Writer;
   public FooWriter()
   {
      Writer = new StreamWriter("MyFile.txt", false);
   }
   public void Write(string line)
   {
     Writer.WriteLine(line);
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
        Writer.Dispose();
   }
}


// use it

using (var writer = new FooWriter())
{
  foreach (var s in args)
                writer.Write(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd change your implementation like so:

- Make the class implement IDisposable
- Initialize the writer in the constructor
- Remove the exception

  public class FooWriter : IDisposable
  {
      public StreamWriter Writer { get; private set; }

  ```
  public FooWriter(string fileName)
  {
      Writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false);
  }

  public void Write(string line)
  {                        
      Writer.WriteLine(line);
  }      

  public void Dispose()
  {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposeManaged)
  {
      if (disposeManaged)
          Writer.Dispose();
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: I'd recommend making your protected Dispose virtual.

Comment: Oops, fixing. Odd that I can't get the syntax highlight for the first/last rows...What am I doing wrong?